# Laravel 5.2: ReflectionException: Class log does not exist test inside vendor package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm facing problem while creating tests inside vendor package. all is working fine if I'm doing only match values in test. But if I'm using `$this->post($url)` or `$this->get($url)` then I'm getting `ReflectionException: Class log does not exist` exception. I did research on this, but not getting solution.

Below is my vendor package `composer.json` file.

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description.",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "license",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~5.0",
        "cyvelnet/laravel5-fractal": "^2.0",
        "spatie/laravel-fractal": "^3.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "NAMESPACE\\": "src",
            "Test\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

And below is my TestCase.php class inside vendor package

```
<?php

namespace Test;

use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{

    protected $faker;

    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/api/v1/';

    protected $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ];

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->faker = Faker::create();
    }

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../../../../bootstrap/app.php';
        $app->singleton('NAMESPACE\Providers\PackageServiceProvider');

        $app->singleton(
            \Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel::class
        );

        $app->singleton(
            \Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::class
        );

        return $app;
    }
}
```

And when I'm running test then I'm getting this error

```
root@0fd1951e0b12:/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys# vendor/bin/phpunit 
PHPUnit 4.8.35 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Warning:    The Xdebug extension is not loaded
        No code coverage will be generated.

E

Time: 72 ms, Memory: 8.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Test\App\Http\Controllers\ListingControllerTest::testIndex
ReflectionException: Class log does not exist

/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:629
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:697
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:849
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:804
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:773
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:629
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:697
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:230
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:731
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:629
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:697
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1178
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:279
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:105
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:515
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:110
/var/www/something/vendor/lucky/luckys/tests/App/Http/ListingControllerTest.php:40

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

ListingsController `testIndex()`

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $url = $this->baseUrl . 'listings/new?page[limit]=10&page[offset]=0';
    $this->get($url)
        ->seeJsonStructure($this->standardJsonStructure)
        ->assertResponseStatus(200);
}
```

Please help me. I spend too much time on this.. but not getting any clue what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show `Test\App\Http\Controllers\ListingControllerTest::testIndex`?

Comment: @Jerodev Updated my question. Please check.